# Assign variable and change property in same line

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a question on typescript:
I have an interface like following:

```
interface MyInterface {
  option1?: string;
  option2?: string;
  // more options
}
```

In another file, I would instantiate an instance of it:

```
const defaultVar: MyInterface {
  option1: 'defaultValue1',
  option2: 'defaultValue2'
}
```

Is there any way, to assign the default value to another variable and set specifics to some options? I am not even sure of the notation. Could maybe be:

```
const specificVar: MyInterface = defaultVar {
  option2: 'specificValue'
}
```

I want to define a bunch of constants, that all derive from a common default, and only adopt necessary values.

Thanks,
Benjamin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the object [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```
interface MyInterface {
    option1?: string;
    option2?: string;
    // more options
}

const defaultVar: MyInterface = {
    option1: 'defaultValue1',
    option2: 'defaultValue2'
}

const specificVar: MyInterface = {
    ...defaultVar,
    option2: 'specificValue'
}
```

The code above creates a new object and assigns all properties of `defaultVar` to `specificVar`. We can also add extra properties that override properties in the new object.

Comment: Great, exactly what I have been looking for!